# Determine whether the points lie on a straight line.

Tags: 3d

Determine whether the points $A(2, 6, 2)$, $B(3, 10, 0)$, $C(1, 4, 3)$ lie on a straight line.

Is there a formula to solve this question? What is it?

Comment: Do you know how to get the area of a triangle given the coordinates?

Comment: I would approach this by considering the vectors $AB$ and $AC$. What is the angle between these vectors?

Comment: not really, I'm relativly to 3d co-ordinate systems

Comment: Subtract $A-B$ and $A-C$ and taking their [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) you can compute the angle between them. You can also use the [signed length of the cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Applications) which will also tell you the order in which the points are in the line.

Comment: I have the answer and it said 
AB = (1,4,-2)
x=2+t  y=6+4t. z=2-2t 
I want to know how to solve this using this technique

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, use that $$\vec{x}=\vec{x_0}+t\vec{a}$$ where $t$ is a real number.
And the equation of the straight line is given by $$\vec{x}=[2;6;2]+t[1;4;-2]$$ so we get
$$[1;4;3]=[2;6;2]+t[1;4;-2]$$ and now compute $$t$$

$$1=2+t$$
$$4=6+4t$$ so $$t=-1$$ and $$t=-\frac{1}{2}$$ and we get no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vectors
$$
\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB} \quad \text{and}\quad\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}.
$$
That is, the vector that takes you front point $A$ to point $B$, and the one that takes you from point $A$ to point $C$. Naturally, if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all colinear, $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}$ and $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}$ will be parallel. *One* way to test this is to exam the unit vectors in the directions of 
$\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}$ and $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}$:

$$
u_1 = \frac{\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}}{\| \overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}\|} \quad \text{and}\quad u_2 =\frac{\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}}{\| \overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}\|}.
$$

If $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}$ and $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}$ are parallel, then either $u_1 = u_2$ or $u_1 = -u_2$. This is equivalent to testing whether $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}$ and $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}$ can be expressed as linear combinations of one another, i.e. $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}= c\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}$ for some scalar $c$.

You could also exam the projections of these vectors onto one anther. If $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AB}$ and $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{AC}$, then either
$$
u_1 \cdot u_2 = 1 \quad \text{or} \quad u_1 \cdot u_2 = -1.
$$
This is, of course, just a different way to express the same relationship.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, the three points are colinear iff $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$ are linearly dependent, i.e., one is a scalar multiple of the other. In three dimensions, the cross product of two vectors vanishes iff they are linearly dependent, so compute $(B-A)\times(C-A)$ and see if this is the zero vector.

Equivalently, the determinant of the matrix $[A,B,C]$ is equal to the volume of the paralellepiped with edges $\overline{OA}$, $\overline{OB}$ and $\overline{OC}$. If the three points are colinear, this paralellepiped “collapses” and has zero volume—the above determinant vanishes.